# CustomListViewAdapter cannot be applied in fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

Any idea why this crashes on open? I am getting no errors now. I have read through the tutorial again and cannot see why my implementation is crashing.

Even with the OnItemClickListener() taken out it still crashes, I am lost for what the error is.

```
public class findFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    ListView list;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
            "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };

    public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
            "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
            "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
            "Mixed Fruits" };

    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.test,
            R.drawable.test, R.drawable.test, R.drawable.test };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.find, container, false);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.imglist, rowItems);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
          list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
    list.setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

Comment: The tutorial I was following: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Comment: I just checked the tutorial you were following. It explains everything perfectly correct. You just need to read carefully not to miss anything. In that case, you missed that your Activity needs to implement OnItemClickLIstener.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda its fragment i guess not activity

Comment: In the tutorial its the Activity but in this case yes, it is the Fragment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
  CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.imglist, rowItems);
```

`getActivity()` returns the activity this fragment is associated with. You need activity context not `this`

Edit:

```
   public class findFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener{
```

You need to override `onItemClick`

Keep

```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: what about the setOnItemClickListener, I still get an error for that. "setOnItemClickListener
(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)
in AdapterView cannot be applied
to
(android.app.Activity)"

Comment: You class needs to implement `OnItemClickListener`. Check that

Comment: @user1902535 did i ask you to use getActivity @  `list.setOnItemClickListener(this);`. i never suggested that

Comment: You did not implement the onItemClickListener for your Fragment. Please edit your question with your current code.

Comment: @user1902535 a crash means a excpetion in logcat post the same here

Comment: I've found the problem, it was in a different file. Thanks for your help